# Need .NET hosting provider that can access Oracle databases

Tags: hosting, asp.net, oracle

I'm looking for a hosting provider of IIS/ASP.NET sites that also allows access to Oracle databases (at a minimum they'd need to install the Oracle instant client plus Oracle ODBC drivers).  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would truly suggest you to have a look at ASPHostDirectory. This host provides a truly flexible hosting and they would "probably" allow you to install Oracle db and Oracle ODBC driver in case you have a decent budget.

I personally have not hosted an Oracle database before, however, I do host RIA Service (Silverlight 3) application - a very NEW technology by Microsoft - with them. Initially, I would have to request them to install it and surprisingly, they do allow me to do so. I am excited to understand that they are very flexible when coming to "understand" the customer needs.

As long as the Oracle does not cause any issue to their server, I am almost positive that they will certainly give you a "go-ahead" :)

Answer (score 0):

I could offer you some recommendations but I would need a bit more information.
compliance regulations?
storage requirements?
shared , dedicated or cloud?

Comment: 1. Compliance regulations are not an issue.
2. I wouldn't need much local storage, most of my stuff doesn't persist on the server (.pdf files before they are purged, code).  Anything with a few GB, or more, would do fine.
3. I'd consider any of the 3 options.  I'm looking at EC2 since then I could do whatever I want but paying ~$1,000 per year is a little much for me.